# Take first some character of string but if particular character will come consider that character also

Tags: python, regex

First,I want to take the 23 characters from the string if [0-9]* will occur before 23 character then include [0-9]*as whole word.
Suppose i have a string:

```
x = I have a car with tha id 6356

I have tried with x[:23]
```

but it is used to take the the first 23 characters. this will fail in the following situation:

```
x = I have a car with id [0-9]*[\s]
x1 = color id [0-9]* with [0-9]*[\s]
x2 = id [0-9]*[\s] with [0-9]*[\s] has index no:[0-9]*[\s]
x3 = id[\s] with[\s] model[\s] has index no[\s][0-9]*

output of x:  I have a car with id [0
output of x1: color id [0-9]* with [0
output of x2: id [0-9]* with [0-
output of x3: id[\s] with[\s] model[\
```

expected Output:

```
x: I have a car with id [0-9]*[\s]
x1: color id [0-9]* with [0-9]*[\s]
x2: color id [0-9]* with [0-9]*[\s]
x3: id[\s] with[\s] model[\s]
```

Comment: I am not quite sure, do you want to find real numbers (like `6356`) or do you want to find the regular expression syntax for numbers **itself** in the string (`[0-9]*`)?

Comment: Please see the modified question..

Answer (score 1):

Just see if that substring is in there. If it is, shift `position` up until it's past that substring:

```
x = 'color id [0-9]* with [0-9]*[\s]'
substring = '[0-9]*'
position = 23

length = len(substring)
index = x.find(substring, position - length)

if position - length < index < position + length - 1:
    position = index + length

print x[:position]
```

Comment: @SuryaGupta: My code shouldn't be hard to modify. It's pretty generic.

Comment: Much nicer answer.  +1 here.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do the trick:

```
^.{23}\d*
```

This result into:

> '*This long string is chopped off.*' results in '*This long string is cho*'.
>   '*My phone number is 061234567891 is cool.*' results in '*My phone number is 061234567891*'.

Read the first group of a match and you'll have your string.

```
m = re.match(r"^.{23}\d*", x)
result = m.group(0)
```